# LINQ query to get a max value from a nested collection

Tags: entity-framework, linq, max

I have 3 entities - User, UserGroup and Group. User and UserGroup has many-to-many relationship and Group and UserGroup has one-to-many relationship. So on EF side, User object has a UserGroup collection and UserGroup has a Group property. Group entity has a property called Level, which is a number giving the group sort of a rank

I want to retrieve all users, along with the Group with the max Level. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Using tuples you could do something like:

```
 Users.Select(u => (u, u.UserGroups.Select(ug => (ug.Group, ug.Group.Level))
    .OrderByDescending(t => t.Item2).FirstOrDefault()?.Item1)))
```

Assuming I've understood your description (posting code would be better).